# Reduce() with a regular function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, reduce, callable

I want to calculate the product sum of two lists using reduce() and a regular function.

The regular function to return the product is defined as:

```
    def func(maturity, weight):
        return maturity * weight
```

and the reduct function is like:

```
reduce(func, zip(terms, weights))
```

An error

```
"TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'"
```

then appears. Is there any way to pass the regular function instead of lambda to calculate the product sum of the two lists?

Comment: Can you please format your question to be more readable ? and provide example of how `terms` and `weights` looks like.

Comment: Looks like you want: `map(func, terms, weights)`... In this case - if your function isn't doing more than multiplying you can use a builtin for that, eg: `result = map(operator.mul, terms, weights)`

Comment: Really sorry about the terrible format. I tried indenting the codes as the instruction says but the codes somehow didn't show in a neat way.

Comment: I get it! I misunderstood how reduce works. I should use map to get a list of products and them use reduce to sum them up.

Comment: @SiyuZhuang: Use `sum` to sum them up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mis-understanding the use of `reduce`. What it does is apply an operation repeatedly on a vector to produce a scalar as the end result. What you want to do is apply the same function on separate elements which are not related. For that purpose, you need `map`:

```
out = map(func, terms, weights)
```

---

As Jon Clements noted, if your function is as simple as element-wise multiplication, you might consider using `operator.mul` instead:

```
import operator
out = map(operator.mul, terms, weights)
```

Comment: Unless `terms` or `weights` are both tuples, then the output from `map` will be a `list` in 2.7 anyway... so the `list` might well be redundant here. (And as per my comment on the question - if the only action is to multiple the two, then using `operator.mul` is not only fairly obvious what it does, but will probably be ever so slightly faster...)

Answer (score 0):

Error is because you are multiplying  tuples, 
Both arguments in `func` are tuples which looks like this

> ('A', 1), ('B', 2)

If you take elements on index 1 it will work.

```
def func(maturity, weight):
    return maturity[1] * weight[1]


terms = ['A', 'B', 'C']
weights = [1, 2]

reduce(func, zip(terms, weights))
```

[snippet](https://trinket.io/python/c9510551e0)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work that way. There will be a TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: You can check snippet at the end of the answer, it works without exception in python2. You did not provide examples of `terms` and `weighs` values so I used my own guess.